# Why isn't Google Maps rendering in an iOS webview, but it does in a browser?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, google-maps, uiwebview

I have a website that's being displayed in an iOS app through a UIWebView. When I open this page in a browser on my desktop it loads the map and renders the tiles no problem ([example](http://tw80000.github.io/app/walkingmap/)). However, when the same page is loaded in the webview in the app, the tiles do not render. However, if the user picks a location from the menu at the top, the map renders after the function call to calculate the directions. This makes me think it's a timing issue of sorts, as the map is obviously working and loading, but not rendering right away as it does in the browser.

Comment: Can you show your UIWebView implementation?

Comment: It's not a problem anymore. Thank you though.

Comment: @TW80000: Do you remember how you fixed this issue? It would be great for other users having the same problem.

Comment: I wish I did but unfortunately I don't, really sorry.